# What exactly is engine design speed?

Tags: jet-engine

Any further information is welcome, this is what I have learned so far:

Engines are designed to operate at a certain RPM (N1). The compressor consists of small 'wings' which are fixed in position, so the angle of attack will vary only by engine speed and forward speed. The engine design speed should be 85-95% N1 for most turbofan engines, this results in an optimum airflow through the compressor. Above or below a higher risk exists for an engine to stall.

Comment: The "wings" inside the engine are called "vanes". They are not as "fixed" as you may think, they float in the hub to allow for thermal expansion/contraction, but they do not vary the angle.

Comment: correct thanks, term fixed was referring to the angle of attack.

Comment: @RonBeyer: Well, variable stators are fixed radially and also vary the angle of attack ;)

Comment: @ymb1 I don't think a lot of turbofan engines used in commercial aviation have variable stator designs, but yes, they do exist (mostly in a military context to avoid compressor stall/surge). GE has a 10-stage with the first few being variable but I'm not sure it's used anywhere but military aircraft, or if its still in the development stage.

Comment: @RonBeyer: Many civilian turbofans have them, the CFM56 for instance, the #1 most selling turbofan.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know they made it into production engines.

Comment: @ymb1: I was under the impression that essentially _all_ modern turbofans, even civil ones, had VSVs.

Comment: @Vikki-formerlySean: I think you meant to tag Ron :)

Comment: @ymb1: Actually, I was responding to your comment that _only_ "many" civilian turbofans had them.  :-)

Comment: @Vikki-formerlySean: But I didn't say "modern" :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Engine design speed* is the shaft RPM and vane pitch which yields the rated thrust that the engine was originally intended to furnish. This will typically be quoted for takeoff at or near sea level at a standard ambient temperature (including a time limit to control maximum temperatures inside the engine) and for optimum cruise conditions at altitude (which will include specification of nominal fuel burn rate in pounds per hour).